Bootstrap 5 validation not working with .NET 8 ASP.NET Core
I´m trying to use bootstrap 5 styling for my error messages in my application. In a previous project the input field would have a red border and a warning triangle if the validation failed due to the required-attribute not being met in the model.
However, in my current project I cannot get this to work, the validation message simply will not appear inside the div. The error message that I set in the ModelState also does not appear. However, if I move the @Html.ValidationMessageFor outside of the invalid-feedback div, it appears as it should but with no styling on the text or the associated input field. From my understanding, this is because the input-field does not get the 'is-invalid' class added to it when an error is received from the model. Is it possible for the is-invalid class to be added automatically to the input-field without using some javascript? Here is my code:
View
@model TestProject.Models.TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <form class="row g-3">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", id = "name", required = "required" })
                <div class="invalid-feedback" id="validationFeedback">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                    Error should appear here
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
}


Model
public class TestModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]       
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}

Controller
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        if(model.Name == "Error")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Error occured");
        }

        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something.
            return View(model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}

I have assured that the correct scripts are used in my layout-file:
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

A previous project which I have worked on that has a huge codebase and runs on .NET 2.0 has form in the structure that I provided. I could not find any global javascripts or the like which set the is-invalid class on the input or any other styling "manually" in that project. It works magically in that older project somehow, and I am wondering if this is possible to do in my current project?

You can use display classes to display class="invalid-feedback manually for example: d-block
Here is an example you can refer to:
<div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                   
 </div>



